# How to set default timeout in Apache HttpClient 4.5? (fluent)

Tags: java, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.5 (with fluent interface) in a Java console application. I noticed, that its default timeout value seem to be infinite, but i have to use a non-infinite timeout value for the requests i send. And i would like to use the same timeout value for all requests.

How do i **globally** set the default connection-timeout and socket-timeout values, so that i do not have to set them every place in the code where i send a request?
(Remember i use the fluent interface)

---

***Example:***

Right now, each place in my code where i send a request i do something like: (simple example)

```
HttpResponse response = Request.Get(url)
   .connectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) // <- want to get rid of this
   .sessionTimeout(SESSION_TIMEOUT)       // <- and this
   .execute()
   .returnResponse();
```

What i would like to do, is to set the default value once and for all, at the beginning of my program. Something like:

```
SomeImaginaryConfigClass.setDefaultConnectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
SomeImaginaryConfigClass.setDefaultSessionTimeout(SESSION_TIMEOUT);
```

so that i can just send a request like this

```
HttpResponse response = Request.Get(url).execute().returnResponse();
```

without setting the timeout parameters on every single call.

I have seen some answers on the net, but they're either for old versions of Apache HttpClient (i.e. doesn't work), or they talk about using a builder or passing a config class along or other approaches way too complicated for my needs. I just want to set the default timeout values, nothing fancier than that. Where do i do this?

Comment: Maybe you could achieve this extending Request class and defining your custom timeout. Them use the new class to build ur requests

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sorry for delay, that's a good idea. Or just create a class with static methods for get(), put(), post(), etc. It's a shame that you have to write boilerplate code just to change a setting, but i might end up doing this :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could use a custom `Executor` to do so

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
        .build();
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
        .setSoTimeout(5000)
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .build();

Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(client);
executor.execute(Request.Get("http://thishost/")).returnResponse();
executor.execute(Request.Get("http://thathost/")).returnResponse();
```

Comment: Thank you, good idea! I will keep the question open i bit, in case someone knows the simple way to set the setting without boilerplate. 

If you know that there is no way to change the global setting, feel free to add that to your answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: (There might very well not be a way... It might be the case that HttpClient was made for doing more complicated http-stuff and perhaps is not the most convenient library for just sending standard http-requests - it makes sense if they're concerned about one place in the code changes the global setting that another place in the code (or a library, if you're using a library using HttpClient too) relied upon, for example)

Comment: I am fairly certain there is no better (less verbose) way. HC fluent APIs are also quite old and certain things have not been fully thought through. Feel free to raise a JIRA with the project or better yet submit a PR at GitHub